# jQuery DatePicker - defaultDate using $_GET['date']

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, get

I'm having troubles with the following code:

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://jqueryui.com/latest/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8rc1/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8rc1/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({ gotoCurrent: false,
          onSelect: function(date, inst) { window.location = "diary.php?date="+date; },
          dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
          defaultDate: <?php if(isset($_GET['date'])) { echo $_GET['date']; } else { echo "null"; } ?>
      });
  });
</script>
```

---

For some reason, when I select a date and switch pages - it doesn't go to the `defaultDate` that is in the `$_GET['date']` paramter. Instead it goes off to some random page. The `defaultDate` description says it will accept strings in the same format set in the code.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi @Danny - it'd be a nice gesture to @Pekka if you'd check the "Accept" checkbox to mark that his answer was what you needed to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing quotes around your value.

```
defaultDate: '<?php if(isset($_GET['date'])) { echo $_GET['date']; } else { echo "null"; } ?>'
```